# 'Stretching' an image depending on post size

Tags: php, html, css, forums

On the [World of Warcraft forums](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5889309137#1) they have a neat style set up that I'd like to emulate.  I didn't know how to do it, so I decided to dig through their stylesheets and grab the pieces of it and put them together to learn how to make a style similar.

When digging through the stylesheets, I found [this](http://us.battle.net/wow/static/images/layout/cms/post_bg.jpg) image.  As you can see, it's the background for their forum posts, but it's a fixed size.  **Here's my question - how are they dynamically creating more length if a user's post is much longer than the picture is?**

On a test website I grabbed the same CSS they used for that section.  They have it set on overflow:hidden; so that it doesn't keep multiplying the image.  Naturally, copying parts of their code gets me this mess on the [test website](http://www.mylifeiscode.com/index2.php#).

It works correctly for smaller posts, since they just have to cut it off, but I'm assuming they have maybe a very thin (set width, perhaps 1 pixel in height) .jpg image that they are multiplying depending on the size of the forum post.

Does anybody know how I might go about doing this?

P.S.  Naturally I'm not going to be using their images and such - I'm only copying it for now just to understand how to make my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

CSS:

```css
.post 
 {
   background:#1A0F08 url(http://us.battle.net/wow/static/images/layout/cms/post_bg.jpg) top no-repeat; 
 }
```

(the image and the color are those really used, hope they don't sue me for that :) )

is what you're looking for. The background image is positioned on top and stays there, while the rest of the container's height has the same background color that the image fades to (using a gradient). So it's just an illusion of a stretched image, but effectively is just that you don't see the interruption where the image ends

Comment: @AdnanShammout yeah, that's making me crazy. DO you know by chance if there's some lang:css option to add in these case to tell the markdown how to behave?

Comment: @DamienPirsy, you can add `<!-- language-all: lang-css -->` before your code block. I fixed it for you

Answer (score 3):

It looks like their background color for the post is the same as the color at the very bottom of that image. That way it just "fades" in - the image does not actually change size.

Example CSS would be:

```css
#yourPostSelector {
  background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
  background-position: top left; /* or 'top center' - whatever works for you */
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-color: #000000; /* pick the bottom color of your background image */
}
```

Comment: In that case, yeah - but what if I wanted to put, say, borders around the top and bottom of the pictures?  (Custom borders, not generated.)

Comment: When you say "pictures" do you mean of the background-image or of the entire post itself (that contains the background-image at the top and the color through the rest of the area)?

Comment: Ignore that - even with what I was thinking (desinging fancy borders in photoshop for the top and bottom), your answer would still be applicable.

I was overthinking it!  Thank you!

Comment: You can use CSS3 to use an image as a border using the border-image property - http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp . It is not entirely compatible with most browsers yet, though - http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image

Comment: Heh, interesting. Funny how the lack of some whitespace will ruin SO's syntax highlighting. Thanks for the edit, Adnan.

Answer (score 1):

Just change you background color which you have used is **#00000***

It should be changed to the color of the background image which you use, basically the bottom part so that it blends perfectly. Presently as per your present image the code would be like this :-

```
.body {
    background: url("../images/post_bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 0 #1A0F09;
    clear: both;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 990px;
}
```

Update this class and check the result, if you don't understand comment here would make you understand.